# Orders are not displayed at merchant console

Tags: node.js, mastercard

I have developed an app in nodejs where I have integrated the Mastercard payment method and it was working fine till Friday. But now when I send money from MasterCard to the merchant account it gives the success response but there is nothing on the merchant console. here is my response

```
       "paymentInfoList": [
            {
                "url": "https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/57/merchant/merchant/order/order-1598868168410/transaction/transaction-1598868195864",
                "mthd": "PUT",
                "payload": {
                    "apiOperation": "CAPTURE",
                    "transaction": {
                        "amount": "1144",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "reference": 1598868195864
                    }
                },
                "resbody": {
                    "authorizationResponse": {
                        "cardSecurityCodeError": "M",
                        "commercialCardIndicator": "1",
                        "date": "0831",
                        "financialNetworkCode": "MCC",
                        "posData": "1025104006600",
                        "posEntryMode": "812",
                        "processingCode": "000000",
                        "responseCode": "00",
                        "stan": "204684",
                        "time": "100313",
                        "transactionIdentifier": "0114GR"
                    },
                    "gatewayEntryPoint": "WEB_SERVICES_API",
                    "merchant": "GTB123456D00",
                    "order": {
                        "amount": 1144,
                        "certainty": "FINAL",
                        "chargeback": {
                            "amount": 0,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        "creationTime": "2020-08-31T10:03:13.631Z",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "id": "order-1598868168410",
                        "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-08-31T10:03:33.156Z",
                        "merchantAmount": 1144,
                        "merchantCategoryCode": "5399",
                        "merchantCurrency": "USD",
                        "reference": "1598868168410",
                        "status": "CAPTURED",
                        "totalAuthorizedAmount": 1144,
                        "totalCapturedAmount": 1144,
                        "totalRefundedAmount": 0
                    },
                    "response": {
                        "acquirerCode": "00",
                        "acquirerMessage": "Approved",
                        "cardSecurityCode": {
                            "acquirerCode": "M",
                            "gatewayCode": "MATCH"
                        },
                        "gatewayCode": "APPROVED"
                    },
                    "result": "SUCCESS",
                    "sourceOfFunds": {
                        "provided": {
                            "card": {
                                "brand": "MASTERCARD",
                                "expiry": {
                                    "month": "9",
                                    "year": "21"
                                },
                                "fundingMethod": "CREDIT",
                                "issuer": "AFRILAND FIRST BANK",
                                "number": "512345xxxxxx0008",
                                "scheme": "MASTERCARD",
                                "storedOnFile": "NOT_STORED"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "CARD"
                    },
                    "timeOfLastUpdate": "2020-08-31T10:03:33.156Z",
                    "timeOfRecord": "2020-08-31T10:03:33.064Z",
                    "transaction": {
                        "acquirer": {
                            "batch": 20200831,
                            "date": "0831",
                            "id": "GTB_S2I",
                            "merchantId": "mymerchant",
                            "settlementDate": "2020-08-31",
                            "timeZone": "+0100",
                            "transactionId": "0114GR"
                        },
                        "amount": 1144,
                        "authorizationCode": "010602",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "id": "transaction-1598868195864",
                        "receipt": "024410204684",
                        "reference": "1598868195864",
                        "source": "INTERNET",
                        "stan": "205744",
                        "terminal": "GTBS2I04",
                        "type": "CAPTURE"
                    },
                    "version": "57"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**now you can see the response is success but it doesnot display on merchant panel/console**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue of the merchant panel/console. It didn't display the orders the same day but from the next day it was working fine and all the previous orders were there, and new orders were also showing on the console/panel So it was their server problem.